# pjsua and sip registration: error=Invalid URI (PJSIP_EINVALIDURI)

Tags: python, sip, pjsip

I'm trying to use PJSUA for SIP registration:

```
import pjsua as pj
import threading


def log_cb(level, str, len):
    print str

class MyAccountCallback(pj.AccountCallback):
    sem = None

    def __init__(self, account):
        pj.AccountCallback.__init__(self, account)

    def wait(self):
        self.sem = threading.Semaphore(0)
        self.sem.acquire()


    def on_reg_state(self):
        if self.sem:
            self.sem.release()

lib = pj.Lib()

try:
    lib.init(log_cfg = pj.LogConfig(level=0, callback=log_cb))
    lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP, pj.TransportConfig(5080))
    lib.start()

    acc = lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig(username='79xxxxxxxxx', password='my_pass', domain='multifon.ru', proxy='sbc.multifon.ru'))

    acc_cb = MyAccountCallback(acc)
    acc.set_callback(acc_cb)
    acc_cb.wait()

    print "\n"
    print "Registration complete, status=", acc.info().reg_status, \
          "(" + acc.info().reg_reason + ")"

    lib.destroy()
    lib = None

except pj.Error, e:
    print "Exception: " + str(e)
    lib.destroy()
```

If I am using `proxy` parameter, I get follow error:

> Exception: Object: Lib, operation=create_account(), error=Invalid URI
>   (PJSIP_EINVALIDURI)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found solution. Address of the proxy server should be presented in the form of `IP address` and `port number` with `sip:` prefix:

```
acc = lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig(username='79xxxxxxxxx', password='my_pass', domain='multifon.ru', proxy='sip:193.201.229.35:5060')
```

Here `193.201.229.35` - IP address corresponding to the domain address `sbc.megafon.ru`

And a couple of comments on the code:

1) Instead of explicitly specifying IP-address in the proxy field it is better to use the `socket.gethostbyname`:

```
proxy_ip = socket.gethostbyname('sbc.megafon.ru')
proxy_str = 'sip:%s:%s' % (proxy_ip, port)

acc = lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig(username=sip_login, password=sip_password,
                                                   domain=sip_domain, proxy=proxy_str))
```

2) In line 
`lib.create_transport (pj.TransportType.UDP, pj.TransportConfig (5080))` port can be set to `0` - the operating system will automatically choose a free port.